# SSH "Access denied" before I'm prompted for password

Tags: centos, ssh

I recently set up a new CentOS 5 server, which has OpenSSH installed by default.

When I connect with PuTTY, the SSH server tells me "access denied" before prompting me for a password. Once I provide the password I log in to my shell fine. It never used to work seemingly out of order like that before, and there's nothing strange in the security log when I log in, just a successful login.

```
login as: admin
Access denied
admin@gold's password:
Last login: Sun Jul 17 00:26:50 2011 from pool-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.phlapa.fios.verizon.net
```

I made one change in the default config to change `PermitRootLogin` to no.

I also upgraded PuTTY to the latest version on the same day as setting up the server, though that's probably unrelated.

Comment: look at/post the output of ssh -v your-server and tail -f /var/log/secure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck "Attempt GSSAPI authentication (SSH-2 only)" under SSH -> Auth -> GSSAPI.

Comment: Bingo. This was exactly my issue. Is this just a CentOS build that prints that message? Or is it something else?

Comment: It seems that problem is in `GSSAPIAuthentication` option set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in RedHat-like distributives (CentOS, Scientific Linux, etc.).

Comment: Yep, just noticed that difference to my Debian box. Good call!

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that it's trying some other authentication method, such as public-key, before falling back to password?  I'm wondering if maybe your permissions on `~/.ssh/` (and the usual files inside there) are wrong on either the client or the server end.  Maybe it's saying "access denied" because it wasn't allowed to read your id_rsa.pub on the server side, or your id_rsa on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

In putty UNCHECK Attempt Auth Using Pageant in your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I bet on a PAM module. Which modules are in the ssh auth chain?